# Check opened WAN ports via script matching iptables and netstat?

Tags: bash, networking, iptables, netstat

I'm trying to understand if there is the possibility to understand opened WAN ports on different devices that i can't connect to the internet and i can only scan by matching netstat and iptables rules.

My aim is to check all UPD/TCP ports only exposed on WAN, i'm not interested in LAN ports and i was planning to run a bash script but i don't really know how to do that.

I've tried by doing a sort of check between iptables(outgoing connections allowed) and netstat

Playing a little bit with netstat i managed to get all the tcp and upd ports with:

```
netstat -tuna | awk '{print $4}' | sed -e 's/.*://' | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

now i should check which ports are allowed to reach the WAN via Iptables, how should i check that ?

Comment: If you're interested in ports open on the WAN side only, shouldn't you try to match the output of `netstat` against the IP address of your WAN interface first ?

Comment: **nmap** is out of question?